# MongoDb : shows different result in find and aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Shows different result in find and groupby query, please someone explain.

```
db.ClinicalStudies.find({
        'DT_referenceData.SubIndication': { '$in': ['Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma', 'Renal Papillary Cell Carcinoma', 'Renal Chromophobe Carcinoma', 'Renal Non-Clear Cell Carcinoma'] },
        'CPSA_AbberationsInfo.GeneName': { '$in': ['VHL'] },
        'CPSA_AbberationsInfo.Type': 'MUT',
        'CPSA_AbberationsInfo.isProfileAdded': { '$eq': 1 },
    }
).count();
```

Count is 140 documents, I then use the following aggregation and expect the same result:

```
db.ClinicalStudies.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$CPSA_AbberationsInfo"},
{"$match":{"$and":[{"CPSA_AbberationsInfo.Type":"MUT"},
{"CPSA_AbberationsInfo.isProfileAdded":{"$eq":1}},
{"DT_referenceData.SubIndication":{"$in":["Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma","Renal Papillary Cell Carcinoma","Renal Chromophobe Carcinoma","Renal Non-Clear Cell Carcinoma"]}}]}},
{"$group":{"_id":"$CPSA_AbberationsInfo.GeneName","y":{"$sum":1}}},
{"$project":{"name":"$_id","_id":0,"y":1}},{"$sort":{"y":-1}}])
```

Output:

```
[
    { 'y': 88, 'name': 'VHL' },
    { 'y': 75, 'name': 'PBRM1' },
];
```

Comment: these two commands do different things, the `find` just counts number of documents ( and a document contains an array with multiple results ), the aggregation counts the sub documents as you unwind the array.

Comment: In the `find` method you have a query filter which is same as the `aggregate` method's `$match` stage. The `{ '_id': 0, 'DT_referenceData.PatientId': 1 }` in the find is a projection. Then you are counting the number of documents returned by the query. The `aggregate` has many stages and the data is transformed in different stages ($group, $unwind, $sort, etc.) and hence different results. In summary, both are different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Find query treats entire array as single document

```
db.inventory.insertOne([
...     { "item": "journal", "instock": [ { "warehouse": "A", "qty": 5 }, { "warehouse": "C", "qty": 15 } ] },
...     { "item": "notebook", "instock": [ { "warehouse": "C", "qty": 5 } ] },
...     { "item": "paper", "instock": [ { "warehouse": "A", "qty": 60 }, { "warehouse": "B", "qty": 15 } ] },
...     { "item": "planner", "instock": [ { "warehouse": "A", "qty": 40 }, { "warehouse": "B", "qty": 5 } ] },
...     { "item": "postcard", "instock": [ { "warehouse": "B","qty": 15 }, { "warehouse": "C", "qty": 35 } ] }
... ]) 
query: db.inventory.find( { "instock.qty": 5, "instock.warehouse": "A" } )

Output:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2717"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a271a"), "item" : "planner", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 40 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 5 } ] }
```

Returns two documents,

1st result did match as queried "instock.qty": 5, "instock.warehouse": "A"

2nd result found "warehouse" : "A" in first document and "qty" : 5 in second document

where as in $unwind splits the array embedded documents and treats as separate document.

```
db.inventory.aggregate([{$unwind:'$instock'}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2717"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2717"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2718"), "item" : "notebook", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2719"), "item" : "paper", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 60 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2719"), "item" : "paper", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a271a"), "item" : "planner", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 40 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a271a"), "item" : "planner", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a271b"), "item" : "postcard", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a271b"), "item" : "postcard", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 35 } }
```

so following query returns single document

```
db.inventory.aggregate([{$unwind:'$instock'},{$match:{$and:[{"instock.warehouse" : "A", "instock.qty" : 5 }]}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63061a1bb87c1278047a2717"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 } }
```